Using stored character tables in GAP
I will use the Harada-Norton group $HN$ as my example. In GAP, the table of irreducible characters can be gotten from memory by Irr(CharacterTable("HN")); and the table of irreducible character of one of the maximal subgroups ($A_{12}$ in this case) can be gotten by Irr(CharacterTable(Maxes(CharacterTable("HN"))[1]));
I do not see how one could use these pre-existing tables to speed up induction/restriction between these two groups, it seems to me that the subgroup relation isn't actually stored anywhere, and if I create $HN$ as a group (AtlasGroup("HN")) it seems to try to create the character tables from scratch.
Is there a way that I can use this stored information to preform induction/restriction?

There are really two different things at play here. The first is the character table library. This library does not only contain the tables itself, but also information about class fusion of table of related groups. This is information that was computed before (sometimes at significant effort) and is stored in the library.
Thus, in your example you could use:
gap> c:=CharacterTable("HN");
CharacterTable( "HN" )
gap> d:=CharacterTable(Maxes(c)[1]);
CharacterTable( "A12" )
gap> FusionConjugacyClasses(d,c);
[ 1, 2, 2, 3, 4, 4, 4, 5, 7, 6, 7, 6, 9, 13, 14, 15, 14, 14, 15, 14, 16, 17,
  19, 19, 20, 20, 20, 22, 26, 29, 29, 30, 30, 31, 30, 33, 34, 34, 41, 44, 48,
  51, 52 ]

to fetch the stored class fusion map $A_{12}\to HN$. With this fusion map, induction and restriction are immediate.
The situation is different when you create $HN$ as a group. (It is not excluded that in future this will be be nicer, but it currently is not.)
AtlasGroup("HN") creates a permutation group of degree $1140000$ and asking for the character table of this group will compute it from scratch, rather than fetch it from the library, and also might arrange conjugacy classes in a different way.

I do not understand how to work with the output of FusionConjugacyClasses, but this answers the question as stated. Thank you

FusionConjugacyClasses is the fusion map -- the class indices in HN where the A12 classes go. It can be given to Induced and Restricted. See the manuakl section 72.9 Restricted and Induced Class Functions.
